# Why do I get such a low on image classification task with neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, keras, r, tensorflow

Below is my r code which I used on this [kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/smeschke/four-shapes/discussion/new).

I'm not sure why the accuracy is so low, but I suspect that I encoded the pixel matrix incorrectly.

I transformed each pixel matrix picture into itself as a row of 200*200 columns and then did that for each pixel matrix making the individual rows for the 14970 pictures in the dataset. I'm not sure if the neural network understands the data and since it is taking data batch after batch I wonder how it can make sense of it.

A quick explanation and some suggested improvements to my code would be appreciated.

```
library(png) 
library(colorspace) 
library(abind) 
library(reticulate) 
library(keras) 

setwd("~/E-books/Coding/Machine Learning with R/Neural Networks/four-shapes") 

# Here I create a list of links to retrieve each image 
files <- list.files(pattern = ".png$", recursive = TRUE) 
filePathFunction <- function(x){ 
a <- matrix(nrow=length(x)) 
for(i in 1:length(x)){ 
conc <- c("~/E-books/Coding/Machine Learning with R/Neural Networks/four-shapes",x[i]) 
a[i] <- paste(conc, collapse="/") 
} 
return(a) 
} 
filePaths <- filePathFunction(files) 
image(readPNG(filePaths[1]), useRaster=TRUE, axes=FALSE) 


#circle is 0 
#square is 1 
#star is 2 
#triangle is 3 

circle <- rep(0,3720) 
circle_array <- array(circle, dim=c(3720,1)) 
square <- rep(1,3765) 
square_array <- array(square, dim=c(3765,1)) 
star <- rep(2,3765) 
star_array <- array(star, dim=c(3765,1)) 
triangle <- rep(3,3720) 
triangle_array <- array(triangle, dim=c(3720,1)) 
labels <- rbind(circle_array,square_array,star_array, triangle_array) 



set.seed(101) 
ind <- sample(nrow(filePaths),round(0.75*nrow(filePaths)),replace=F) 
train_data <- filePaths[ind,] 
test_data <- filePaths[-ind,] 

train_labels <- labels[ind,] 
test_labels <- labels[-ind,] 

train_labels <- to_categorical(train_labels) 
test_labels <- to_categorical(test_labels) 

#trainPathArray and testPathArray reshape each pixel matrix into a 11228x200*200 array and 
#3742x200*200 array matrix 

trainPathArray <- matrix(ncol=200*200, nrow= length(train_data)) 
for(i in 1:length(train_data)){ 
trainPathArray[i,] <- array_reshape(readPNG(train_data[i]), dim= c(1,200*200)) 
} 
testPathArray <- matrix(ncol=200*200, nrow= length(test_data)) 
for(i in 1:length(test_data)){ 
testPathArray[i,] <- array_reshape(readPNG(test_data[i]), dim= c(1,200*200)) 
} 


network <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
layer_dense(units = 1000, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(200*200)) %>% 
layer_dense(units = 1000, activation = "relu") %>% 
layer_dense(units = 4, activation = "softmax") 

network %>% compile( 
optimizer = "rmsprop", 
loss = "categorical_crossentropy", 
metrics = c("accuracy") 
) 
network %>% fit(trainPathArray, train_labels, epochs = 5, batch_size = 12smilie 
metrics <- network %>% evaluate(testPathArray, test_labels)
```

Comment: The only other issue I can locate is that the pixel matrix is too large 200x200.